# Neo4j - property as variable to return

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I'm using python driver for neo4j (neo4j.v1) and I'm trying to write a generic function that gets node's unique id and a property and returns the value of the property of this node with the unique id.

I have tried using the following code without success :

```
def prop_by_node_id(tx, node_id, prop):
    prop = "s." + prop
    result = tx.run("MATCH (s) WHERE s.id = $id return $prop", id=node_id, prop=prop)
```

I serached for a solution in APOC and couldn't find one.
Thank you

Comment: You can make an index on `id` property, so the cypher query will perform better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels, relationship types & properties can't be dynamic into a cypher query.
So you need to generate your cypher query in Python.

Moreover, your query will not be performant, because the label is missing on the node `s`, so you will do a `all node scan` that is really bad.